# Emacs: how to jump to function definition in .el file?

Tags: emacs

I tried to edit my init file. Is there any possible way to quickly jump into function definition of other .el file that has already loaded/required ?

I remember doing this once, but don't remember how...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(function name)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I find that <kbd>C-h C-f</kbd> makes a good keybinding for `find-function` (given that <kbd>C-h f</kbd> is bound by default to `describe-function`)

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-h C-f") 'find-function)`

Comment: This only works for functions that have been loaded, or one that is set up for auto loading.

Comment: Indeed, but it seemed like the best answer given that the question was specifically about loaded elisp functions, and it doesn't require the extra step of generating a TAGS file.

Comment: I just had this exact question, thanks much. I also discovered that there's also `find-function-at-point` (in emacs 23, at least). I bound this to C-h C-f and it works great!

Comment: Some similarly useful functions are: `find-function-on-key`, `find-variable`, and `find-library`.

Comment: If you don't want to have this as a global hotkey, but in emacs-lisp major modes only: `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'find-function-at-point)))`

Answer (score 10):

[As of emacs-25.1](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/2c2b0cd07c143e33af9f7237ef4819c28764a90f/etc/NEWS#L1664), there's a new generic function `xref-find-definitions`. The *xref* built-in package provides a *generic* framework for navigating definitions in code. Probably, it'd take some time for every mode to adjust custom functions for this framework, but, at the very least, `emacs-lisp-mode` already ported.

Comment: Awesome! There was no inverse of `find-function-at-point` AFAIK which really annoyed me. Now it works the way I want!

(The inverse of `xref-find-definitions` is `xref-pop-marker-stack`)

Comment: unfortunately it wont work with tags files generated from .el.gz files.

Comment: @RichieHH are you sure ctags/etags support indexing .el.gz files? Out of curiosity I just made a single derectory with an arbitrary elisp file `add-log.el.tar.gz`, and when I do `ctags -eR .` and `etags add-log.el.tar.gz`, the resulting TAGS file has no definitions.

Answer (score 5):

`etags [options] file1 file2 ...` and then, from inside emacs, do `M-.` to visit the tag.  To go the the next occurrence of the tag, do `M-,`.

Comment: You probably meant `M-.` there :) Not `M-x .`

Answer (score 4):

`find-function` is the way to go. An alternative is to use <kbd>C-h f</kbd>, then click the file name in buffer `*Help*`.