# How to get the path of a elisp program file from inside of the file?

Tags: elisp

When I edit a file, say `current-file-path.el`

I can have the following code:

```
(message (format "Here is the path of the current file %s" (buffer-file-name)))
```

when execting the statement in the buffer of the file when the file is open in a buffer, I got the correct message 
of the path of the file:

```
Here is the path of the current file /home/yubrshen/tmp/current-file-path.el
```

However, if I just load the file, then the message becomes:

```
Here is the path of the current file nil
```

What would be the proper way to find out the path of the file where my code is?
Actually, I'm interested in knowing the directory of the file of my program so that I can load the other files at the same directory through the program.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222183/emacs-how-to-jump-to-function-definition-in-el-file

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for [`symbol-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Where-Defined.html).

Of course, not every symbol is defined in Lisp code loaded from a named file; some are defined in the C source code for Emacs, and some are defined interactively by yourself.

There is also no guarantee that your data files will be packaged in the same location as your source code, so what you are describing should probably be implemented with a package variable instead.

```
(defvar foo-directory (file-name-directory load-file-name)
  "*Directory for data files belonging to package \`foo'.")
```

This should probably use `defcustom` actually, but I'd have to guess too many things about your code to create a meaningful example.

Comment: It would work for my use case, but it's not the most straightforward one. Thanks! My preferred solution is ```load-file-name``` as suggested in the above-referred question and answer.

Comment: You'll notice that my `defvar` does exactly that.